# What ID values are constant to all Sitecore installations?

Tags: constants, sitecore, sitecore6

When making reusable layouts/sublayouts in Sitecore, I often want to access a specific item by ID. This poses a challenge as I'm not certain which items will have the same ID across all Sitecore installations.

The Sitecore root ID (`/sitecore`) is constant at `{11111111-1111-1111-1111-111111111111}`, what other IDs can be stored as a constant without fear of needing to update for each project?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I would guess most of the structural items have the same ids in different installations.

Sitecore has `Sitecore.ItemIds` class which has references to some of the main items.

Here is the list of items it contains

```
public static ID AnonymousUser;
public static ID BranchesRoot;
public static ID ConditionalRenderingsGlobalRules;
public static ID ContentRoot;
public static ID DefaultRibbon;
public static ID DevicesRoot;
public static ID EveryoneRoleID;
public static ID LanguageRoot;
public static ID LayoutRoot;
public static ID Layouts;
public static ID MediaLibraryRoot;
public static ID Null;
public static ID PlaceholderSettingsRoot;
public static ID Policies;
public static ID RootID;
public static ID Shell;
public static ID ShellAll;
public static ID ShellDefault;
public static ID SystemRoot;
public static ID TemplateRoot;
public static ID Undefined;
[Obsolete("This ID has been deprecated.")]
public static ID VirtualStructures;
public static ID WorkflowRoot;
```

If you don't find what you need here I think the best solution is to depend on paths rather than Ids. Paths are easier to read and debug.

Comment: You have a typo, it's Sitecore.ItemIDs